# Is there a excel formula to count how many times an ID appears in a column when the value in another column is YES?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, countif

I have a table with 5 columns.
Column C with - ID numbers that need to be checked.
Column D with - name of the person who should check the ID.
Column E - say if it was checked or not by "YES" or "NO"

However, I need a formula on Columns A and B to show who did the last check and how many time the ID was checked already.

On **column **A**** need to appear the name of who did the last check on a specific ID Taking in consideration the information On **columns C ID number**, **D = person** and **E = is it was checked or not.**

On **column B** I need to count how many times the ID on the column C appear, but only if it YEs on column E. `=COUNTIFS(F:F,F152)+COUNTIFS(J:J,J152="Yes")`

[image]

example in the image the ID number **59461** appear on C2, C6 and C8 and E2, E6 is **YES** and only  E8 the value is **NO**

what would the the best approach to get the result I need for column A and B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess in `A2` you could use:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/((C:C=C2)*((E:E="Yes"))),D:D)
```

In `B2` use:

```
=COUNTIFS(C:C,C2,E:E,"Yes")
```

Not sure it's what you are after, let me know.